# Can you improve my code, prolong segment of a fixed length and annoting it

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello I was trying to work on a figure where I have to show the vectors describing the geometry of my problem. So I want to prolong the segments (here AD) used to describe the mechanism, I use `shorten >=-2cm` to prolong them by a fixed amount. Which create a first problem by drawing not only the vecteur but draw on top of the segment too, and one more problem is the solution I found to label the vector -I would like a node around the tip of the arrow- I have to tweek the `pos` value by hand to place it because it changes with the length (AD)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through,intersections}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,esvect}
\tikzset{
    Points/.style={circle,draw,line width=1pt,minimum width=.4cm,fill=white},
    Vect/.style={line width=.5pt,shorten >=-2cm,-stealth},
    }
    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[Points] (PtA) at (5,2) {}    ;
    \node[Points] (PtB) at (8,4) {}    ;
    \node[Points] (PtD) at ($(PtB)+(-90:3)$) {}    ;
    
    \node[above=0.3cm] at (PtA) {A};
    \node[below=0.3cm] at (PtB) {B}; 
    \node[below=0.3cm] at (PtD) {D}; 

    \draw[red, line width=2pt] (PtA) -- (PtD);

    \draw[Vect] (PtA) -- (PtD) node[pos=1.47] {$\vv{z_2}$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Giving :
[image: segment and prolongation]

On that image you can also see that the result of that prolongation is not in the frame of the standalone figure as you can barely see the tip of the arrow.

Comment: Shortening doesn't update the bounding box. It's not really the best tool for it. Should the arrow just be 2cm on the opposite side of D? What's the requirement exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, quotes}
\tikzset{
  Points/.style={circle, draw, line width=1pt, minimum width=.4cm},
  Vect/.style={
    line width=.5pt, -Stealth, sloped, at end,
    to path={(\tikztotarget)--($(\tikztotarget)!-2cm!(\tikztostart)$)\tikztonodes}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[Points, "A"      ] (PtA) at (5,2)             {};
\node[Points, "B" below] (PtB) at (8,4)             {};
\node[Points, "D" below] (PtD) at ($(PtB)+(-90:3)$) {} ;

\draw[red, line width=2pt] (PtA) -- (PtD);
\draw[Vect] (PtA) to["$\vv{z_2}$"] (PtD);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your proposed changes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw the vector before the connector (red line). I had to define coordinates for this
2. Use `[sloped, above]` for the vector label
3. Defined an `ExtensionFactor` that specifies how long the extension must be relative to the distance between A and D. Calculated the label position using this value such that it lies midway on the extension

Step 2 somehow eliminated the border margin issue too :)

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through,intersections}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,esvect}
\tikzset{
    Points/.style={circle,draw,line width=1pt,minimum width=.4cm,fill=white},
    Vect/.style={line width=.5pt,-stealth},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ExtensionFactor{0.5}
        
        \coordinate (PtA) at (5,2);
        \coordinate (PtB) at (8,4);
        \coordinate (PtD) at ($(PtB)+(-90:3)$);
        \coordinate (PtDex) at ($(PtD)+\ExtensionFactor*(PtD)-\ExtensionFactor*(PtA)$);
        
        \draw[Vect] (PtA) -- (PtDex) node [pos=(1+0.5*\ExtensionFactor)/(1+\ExtensionFactor), sloped, above] {$\vv{z_2}$};
        
        \node[Points] (PtA) at (PtA) {};
        \node[Points] (PtB) at (PtB) {};
        \node[Points] (PtD) at (PtD) {};
        
        \node[above=0.3cm] at (PtA) {A};
        \node[below=0.3cm] at (PtB) {B}; 
        \node[below=0.3cm] at (PtD) {D}; 
        
        \draw[red, line width=2pt] (PtA) -- (PtD);
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I decided to go with the other answer to avoid the calculation of ExtensionFactor by hand fo each segment but thank you for your take.